# Flutter: How to check if a variable is a List<Object?>?

Tags: list, flutter, object, if-statement

Code:

```
print(item);
print(item.runtimeType);
print(item.runtimeType is List);
print(item.runtimeType is List<Object?>);
```

Result:

```
flutter: [null, null]
flutter: List<Object?>
flutter: false
flutter: false
```

I don't know how to get a  `true` for this check...

Answer (score 1):

```
print(item is List<Object?>)
```

Comment: The OP already used that piece of code, but somehow is still returning false.

Comment: @Homan I don't see `item is List<Object?>`, I see `item.runtimeType is List<Object?>`

Answer (score -1):

try this out, and try to tinker with this code:

`var firstList = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; print(firstList.firstWhere((i) => i < 4));`